# ¿Es posible validar antes de crear un objeto en PHP?

Tags: php, poo

Tengo la siguiente duda: ¿es posible validar la forma de un array antes de crear un objeto?

Tengo el siguiente escenario. Estoy creando una apiRest y el programador que consume mi API me envía un post con el siguiente JSON:

```
[
  {
    "Codigo":"1",
    "Nombre":"NESTEA",
    "Presentacion":"1.5 L",
    "Foto":"http://localhost/api/public/img/pepsi.jpg",
    "MarcaId":"1",
    "FamiliaId":"1",
    "ProveedorId":"2",
    "Rating":"5",
    "Estado":"0"
  }
]
```

En el apiRest implementé un método post y debe crear un objeto nuevo con el JSON convertido en array:

```
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
     $postBody = file_get_contents("php://input");
     $jsonToArray = json_decode($postBody,true);

     $producto = new productos($jsonToArray);

     print_r($producto->getCodigo());
     http_response_code(200);
  }
```

Código de la clase:

```
class productos {
     //atributos
     private $Codigo;
     private $Nombre;
     private $Presentacion;
     private $Foto;
     private $MarcaId;
     private $FamiliaId;
     private $ProveedorId;
     private $Rating;
     private $Estado;

     //constructor
     public function productos($array){
            $this->Codigo = $array[0]['Codigo'];
            $this->Nombre = $array[0]['Nombre'];
            $this->$Presentacion = $array[0]['Presentacion'];
            $this->Foto = $array[0]['Foto'];
            $this->MarcaI = $array[0]['MarcaId'];
            $this->FamiliaId = $array[0]['FamiliaId'];
            $this->ProveedorId = $array[0]['ProveedorId'];
            $this->Rating = $array[0]['Rating'];
            $this->Estado = $array[0]['Estado'];
     }

     public function GuardarProducto(){
         return $this->Codigo;
     }
}
```

Hasta aquí todo está bien. El problema surge cuando me dejan de enviar un parámetro. Por ejemplo:

```
[
  {
    "Codigo":"1",
    "Nombre":"NESTEA",
    "Presentacion":"1.5 L",
    "Foto":"http://localhost/api/public/img/pepsi.jpg",
    "MarcaId":"1",
    "FamiliaId":"1",
    "ProveedorId":"2",  
  }
]
```

Me surge el siguiente error:

> **Notice**:  Undefined variable: Presentacion in **C:\xampp\htdocs\api\objetos\productos.php** on line **21**
>
> **Fatal error**:  Cannot access empty property in **C:\xampp\htdocs\api\objetos\productos.php** on line **21**

Lo único que se me ocurre es utilizar `if(isset(array[0]['Estado']){ //validar }`, pero quiero que todos los campos sean requeridos y enviarle un error 400 al programador si no está bien el POST.

¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Comment: Siempre podrías añadir la comprobación antes de llamar al constructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tal como dijiste, con `isset()` y luego la función `header()` para enviarle la respuesta de error.

En el archivo donde recibís los datos podrías usar un bloque `try/catch` y alli manejar el estado de error. Algo asì:

```
try {
   $postBody = file_get_contents("php://input");
   $jsonToArray = json_decode($postBody,true);

   $producto = new productos($jsonToArray);

   print_r($producto->getCodigo());
   http_response_code(200);

} catch (Exception $e) {
   header('HTTP/1.1 400 ' . $e->getMessage());
}
```

Y en la clase enviar una excepción cuando falla alguna validación:

```
if (!isset($array[0]['Estado'])) {
   throw new Exception('El campo Estado es obligatorio');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Según veo la manera más optima de hacer lo que deseas es agregar una propiedad a tu objeto productos o los que crees posteriormente llamada unused, junto con su getter, en la cual vas a ir agregando las propiedades que no te interesa que aparezcan o no cuando recojas el arreglo en el json, por defecto todas las propiedades que tengas serán requeridas, y solo por ellas es que se comprobara para verificar si tu arreglo es valido o no. En mi caso hice una clase llamda Validator para poner alli las funcionalidades de las que me vali para hacer las validaciones. Este es el código:

```
class Validator{

    //Obtiene un arreglo con todas las propiedades de un objeto
    static function getProperties($class)
    {
        $reflection = new ReflectionClass($class);
        $vars = $reflection->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_PRIVATE);
        $result = [];
        //Agrega todas menos 'unused'
        array_walk($vars, function($val, $key) use(&$result){ 
            if($val->name !== 'unused'){
                $result[] = $val->name;
            }   
        });
        return $result;
    }

    //Verifica si el arreglo es correcto basado en las propiedades del objeto obj
    static function checkProperties($jsonArray, $obj, &$missed){
        $props = self::getProperties($obj);
        $unused = call_user_func(array($obj, 'getUnused'),array());
        //Propiedades del objeto que no estan en el arreglo unused
        $real = array_diff($props, $unused);
        //Propiedades que faltan con respecto a las que posee el objeto y son requeridas
        $missed = array_diff($real, array_keys($jsonArray[0]));
        /*Aqui lo que verifico es que no exista ninguna diferencia entre las claves de tu arreglo y las
        propiedades de tu clase*/
        return count(array_intersect($real, array_keys($jsonArray[0]))) == count($props);
    }
}
```

Esta es tu clase **productos**:

```
class productos {
     //atributos
     private $Codigo;
     private $Nombre;
     private $Presentacion;
     private $Foto;
     private $MarcaId;
     private $FamiliaId;
     private $ProveedorId;
     private $Rating;
     private $Estado;
     //Esta es la propiedad donde vas a ir agregando las que no vas a comprobar
     private $unused = [];

     //constructor
     public function productos($array){
            $faltan = [];
            if(Validator::checkProperties($array, $this, $faltan)){             
                $this->Codigo = $array[0]['Codigo'];
                $this->Nombre = $array[0]['Nombre'];
                $this->$Presentacion = $array[0]['Presentacion'];
                $this->Foto = $array[0]['Foto'];
                $this->MarcaI = $array[0]['MarcaId'];
                $this->FamiliaId = $array[0]['FamiliaId'];
                $this->ProveedorId = $array[0]['ProveedorId'];
                $this->Rating = $array[0]['Rating'];
                $this->Estado = $array[0]['Estado'];
            } else {
                //Lanzo una excepción si no es correcta la validación
                throw new Exception("Faltan datos: ".implode(", ", $faltan));
            }
     }

     public function GuardarProducto(){
         return $this->Codigo;
     }

     //Getter a la propiedad unused
     public function getUnused(){
         return $this->unused;
     }
}
```

Y aqui esta el punto de entrada con el que inicias tu código:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
     $postBody = file_get_contents("php://input");
     $jsonToArray = json_decode($postBody,true);
     try{
         $producto = new productos($jsonToArray);
         print_r($producto->getCodigo());
         http_response_code(200);
    } catch(Exception $e){
        http_response_code(400);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola muchas Gracias por tu ayuda el codigo funciona correctamente  solo tengo una pequeña duda

Comment: si por ejemplo quiera  que el campo Estado no fuera Validado
 como podria utilizar  :  $unused = [];

Comment: private $unused = ['Estado'];

Answer (score 2):

Te paso dos formas de implementación, en la segunda forma podes crear mas reglas de validación una vez que sabes que tenes el array completo

**1** como chequear si un array está "completo" (todos los keys definidos en una plantilla)

```
      #!/usr/bin/env php
      <?php
      $postBodyBueno = '[
        {
          "Codigo":"1",
          "Nombre":"NESTEA",
          "Presentacion":"1.5 L",
          "Foto":"http://localhost/api/public/img/pepsi.jpg",
          "MarcaId":"1",
          "FamiliaId":"1",
          "ProveedorId":"2",
          "Rating":"5",
          "Estado":"0"
        }
      ]';

      $postBodyMalo = '[
        {
          "Codigo":"1",
          "Nombre":"NESTEA",
          "Presentacion":"1.5 L",
          "Foto":"http://localhost/api/public/img/pepsi.jpg",
          "MarcaId":"1",
          "FamiliaId":"1",
          "ProveedorId":"2",
          "campoextranodefinido":"undefined"
        }
      ]';

      function ValidateArrayDesdeJson($jsonString='')
      {
          $lasKeys = array(
          'Codigo',  'Nombre', 'Presentacion', 'Foto', 'MarcaId',
          'FamiliaId', 'ProveedorId', 'Rating', 'Estado'
          );
          $jsonToArray = json_decode($jsonString, true)[0];
          $testKeys = array_diff($lasKeys, array_keys($jsonToArray));
          if ($testKeys) :
              $err = '400 - Faltan campos ['.
                implode(', ', $testKeys).']'.PHP_EOL;
            else :
                  $err = '200 - Parece que esta bien'.PHP_EOL;
            endif;
              return $err;
      }

      echo "postBodyBueno:".ValidateArrayDesdeJson($postBodyBueno);
      echo "postBodyMalo:".ValidateArrayDesdeJson($postBodyMalo);
```

Resultado:

```
$ ./checkarraykeys.php
postBodyBueno:200 - Parece que esta bien
postBodyMalo:400 - Faltan campos [Rating, Estado]
```

**2** incluido como check en el constructor

```
  #!/usr/bin/env php
  <?php
  class Producto
  {
      //atributos
      private $Codigo;
      private $Nombre;
      private $Presentacion;
      private $Foto;
      private $MarcaId;
      private $FamiliaId;
      private $ProveedorId;
      private $Rating;
      private $Estado;

      //constructor
      public function __construct( array $attr = []
      ) {
          $this->ValidarAtributosProducto($attr);
          $this->Codigo = intval($attr['Codigo']);
          $this->Nombre = $attr['Nombre'];
          $this->Presentacion = $attr['Presentacion'];
          $this->Foto = $attr['Foto'];
          $this->MarcaI = $attr['MarcaId'];
          $this->FamiliaId = $attr['FamiliaId'];
          $this->ProveedorId = $attr['ProveedorId'];
          $this->Rating = $attr['Rating'];
          $this->Estado = $attr['Estado'];
      }

      private function ValidarAtributosProducto(array $attr = [])
      {
          $lasKeys = array(
          'Codigo',  'Nombre', 'Presentacion', 'Foto', 'MarcaId',
          'FamiliaId', 'ProveedorId', 'Rating', 'Estado'
          );
          $testKeys = array_diff($lasKeys, array_keys($attr));
          if ($testKeys) :
              throw new Exception(
                  'Faltan campos ['.
                  implode(', ', $testKeys).
                  ']'.PHP_EOL
              );
          endif;

          if (0==$attr['Codigo']) :
              throw new Exception(
                  'El Código no es válido ['.$attr['Codigo'].']'.PHP_EOL
              );
          endif;

      }
  }

  $arrayProducto = array( 'Nombre'=>'un producto');
  try {
      $producto = new Producto($arrayProducto);
  } catch(Exception $e) {
      echo '400 - Mensaje: ' .$e->getMessage();
  }
```

Resultado:

```
$ ./classvalidation.php
400 - Mensaje: Faltan campos [Codigo, Presentacion, Foto, MarcaId, FamiliaId, ProveedorId, Rating, Estado]
```

Answer (score 2):

Podrías crearte un método privado en la clase encargado de comprobar que están todos los campos en  el `array` que le pasas al constructor, este método podría ser llamado desde el mismo constructor.

El código quedaría más o menos así:

```
public function Productos( $array ) {
        if($this->validar($array)){
            $this->Codigo       = $array[0]['Codigo'];
            $this->Nombre       = $array[0]['Nombre'];
            $this->Presentacion = $array[0]['Presentacion'];
            $this->Foto         = $array[0]['Foto'];
            $this->MarcaI       = $array[0]['MarcaId'];
            $this->FamiliaId    = $array[0]['FamiliaId'];
            $this->ProveedorId  = $array[0]['ProveedorId'];
            $this->Rating       = $array[0]['Rating'];
            $this->Estado       = $array[0]['Estado'];
        }else{
            //aquí manejas el error
        }


    }
private function validar($array){
        $campos=['Codigo','Nombre','Presentacion','Foto','MarcaId','FamiliaId','ProveedorId','Rating','Estado'];
        $valido=true;
        foreach($campos as $campo){

            if(!array_key_exists($campo,$array[0])){

                $valido =false;
            }
        }
        return $valido;
}

}
```